# Intelligencia UrlRewriter.NET not working properly on IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I'm having an issue getting the following syntax to work:

```
<rewriter>
    <!-- This does NOTHING -->
    <if url="whywontthiswork\.aspx" rewrite="/default.aspx" />

    <!-- This redirects correctly -->
    <redirect url="whywontthiswork\.aspx" to="/default.aspx" />
</rewriter>
```

As noted, the first rule does nothing no matter what I try. The X-Powered-By field on the response for that page request always says "ASP.NET". However, the second rewrite rule always works, and the X-Powered-By field on the response for that request is "ASP.NET,UrlRewriter.NET 2.0".

I believe that IIS is configured properly because it is handling the request correctly for `<redirect />`. The issue is that I don't have any ideas why the first rewrite rule would not execute.

I have tried to search the documentation on [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/), but at this time, it seems their site if offline or no longer in service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorry to answer my own question but I figured out the solution shortly after posting this. I most likely have a different version of UrlRewriter.NET than what was used when these rules were created. Updating the syntax to the following, solved the problem:

```
<if url="whywontthiswork\.aspx">
    <rewrite url="whywontthiswork\.aspx" to="/default.aspx" />
</if>
```

**Edit:**
I was able to confirm that our production environment was using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter version 1.7.0 but the assembly I was using was 2.0.